# idiomatic way to get os err after call

Tags: go

If I do

```
s, err := os.Stat(path)
```

and `err != nil` I need to know if the file doesn't exist vs I don't have permission to access it, etc. How do I get the underlying error code? Reading the `os` package docs it seems to suggest that I read the text of the error string - surely not?

Comment: Convert err to syscall.Errno with something like err.(syscall.Errno) and compare it against the list of provided values.

Comment: that doesnt work "error is *os.PathError, not syscall.Errno "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What [FUZxxl says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043781/idiomatic-way-to-get-os-err-after-call#comment37068727_24043781).

From the [`os.Stat` documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat):

> Stat returns a `FileInfo` describing the named file. **If there is an error, it will be of type `*PathError`.**

`PathError` is documented [on the same page](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError), stating that it holds the operation that caused the error, the path to the file that caused it and the underlying system's error. In case the file was not found when calling `os.Stat`, the returned error would be something like this:

```
&PathError{"stat", "/your/file", syscall.Errno(2)}
```

Since the underlying error is inherently depending on the OS you use, the only thing that you can do is to 
understand `PathError.Err`. For UNIX systems the `syscall` package has the [`Errno` error type](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Errno) returned by syscalls like `syscall.Stat`. You can compare this value with the [constants in the `syscall` package](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#pkg-constants) and handle the error ([Click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/iH3O9l6Lri)):

```
stat, err := os.Stat(file)

if perr, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
    switch perr.Err.(syscall.Errno) {
         case syscall.ENOENT: fmt.Println("No such file or directory.")
         default: panic("Unknown error")
    }
}
```

The shorter way of doing this is to use [`os.IsNotExist`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist) which does [pretty much the above](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/error_unix.go#L23)
and is, most importantly, platform independent:

```
stat, err := os.Stat(file)

if err != nil && os.IsNotExist(err) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: just like to point out the the documentation of PathErr does not say anything about the third field containing a syscall error. The only way to find this out is to read the code (which I am not averse to - but it seems like too much work - hence my question)

Comment: ok - the last one is the 'idiomatic one'. I asked the wrong question.  I should have asked 'how do I tell if the stat call failed because file doesnt exist vs no permission?' - and here is the answer

Comment: @pm100 You're right. I don't think you're supposed to know where that error comes from since there are the `os.Is*(err)` functions to check the error for you in a platform independent way and abstract the syscall package away.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is great, but I wanted add a note about this suggestion:

```
stat, err := os.Stat(file)
if err != nil && os.IsNotExist(err) {
   // ...
}
```

I found that in many cases, I was needing to take different actions depending on
each test, so in reality you have three branches here. Here is code I use for
that:

```
stat, err := os.Stat(file)

if os.IsNotExist(err) {
   // branch one
} else if err != nil {
   // branch two
}

// branch three
```